# HTTP Error 503 The service is unavailable on IIS after windows 10 fall update

Tags: iis

I run IIS on my windows 10 pc and after the fall creators update IIS was no longer installed. I re-added IIS but when I browse to a local site the app pool crashes and the browser displays HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.

This will happen for any app pools on the pc. I deleted app pools and went to `C:\inetpub\temp\appPools` and deleted the directories there, reset IIS and the app pools still crash.

In the event viewer application log I see, "The Module DLL `C:\WINDOWS\System32\inetsrv\authsspi.dll` failed to load.  The data is the error."

In the event viewer system log I see the following:

> A listener channel for protocol 'HTTP' in worker process '5520' serving application pool 'DefaultAppPool' reported a listener channel failure.  The data field contains the error number.

When I search for these errors I see others complaining about windows update causing IIS issues but so far I haven't found a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was the fact that I failed to install windows authentication when I reinstalled IIS. I installed windows authentication and the error is gone.

Comment: How did you do that?

Comment: Go to add/remove programs, windows features, Internet Information Services and check the box for windows authentication.

Comment: Thanks. But in my case It didn't help me. IIS web sites work on any port instead of 80. I need change bindings and add `localhost` in "Host Name" field.